# How to use FL Studio to change adult female voice to little girl voice?

Tags: pitch-shifting, voice-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to change from adult female voice to a little girl voice, I know how to invert the sounds to switch gender, but I don't know how to make it sounds "kiddier".

Comment: what do you mean by 'invert the sounds?'

Comment: Selectable frequency inversion?